# Meteor/Iron-Router: how to define routes using data from settings.json

Tags: meteor, iron-router

For the URL to which a route applies I have a part defined in settings.json, like this

```
baseUrl: '/private'
```

My settings are published and accessible through the collections 'Settings' (on the client). So I tried the following:

```
Meteor.subscribe('settings');

Deps.autorun(function () {
    var settings = Settings.findOne():

   if (settings) {
        Router.map(function () {
            this.route('project', {
                path: settings.baseUrl + '/:projectId,
               controller: 'ProjectController'
            });
        });
   } 
});
```

The problem is that during initialisation the data is not yet on the client available, so I have to wait until the data is present. So far this approach doesn't work (yet). But before spending many hours I was wondering if someone has done this before or can tell me if this is the right approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated answer:

I published solution in repository : https://github.com/parhelium/meteor-so-inject-data-to-html
. Test it by opening url : localhost:3000/test

In this case FastRender package is useless as it [injects collection **data** in the end of **head** tag](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-fast-render/blob/master/lib/server/inject.js) -> line 63.

Inject-Initial package [injects data in the beginning of **head** tag](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-inject-initial/blob/master/lib/inject-server.js) -> line 106.

Needed packages:

```
  mrt add iron-router
  mrt add inject-initial
```

Source code:

```
Settings = new Meteor.Collection("settings");
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    var settings = Injected.obj('settings');
    console.log(settings);
    Router.map(function () {
        this.route('postShow', {
            path: '/'+settings.path,

            action: function () {
                console.log("dynamic route !");
            }
        });
    });
}

if (Meteor.isServer){
    if(Settings.find().count() == 0){
        Settings.insert({path:"test",data:"null"});
    }

    Inject.obj('settings', Settings.findOne());
}
```

Read about security in the bottom of the page : https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-inject-initial/

#### OLD ANSWER :

**Below solution won't work in this specific case as `FastRender` injects data in the end of head tag. Because of that Routes are being initialized before injected data is present.**

It will work when data from Settings collection will be sent together with html.
You can do that using package [FastRender](http://atmospherejs.com/package/fast-render).

Create file `server/router.js` :

```
 FastRender.onAllRoutes(function(path) {
     // don't subscribe if client is downloading resources
     if(/(css|js|html|map)/.test(path)) {
         return;
     }
     this.subscribe('settings');
 });
```

Create also `publish` function:

```
Meteor.publish('settings', function () {
     return Settings.find({});
});
```

The above code means that if user open any url of your app then client will subscribe to "settings" publication  and data will be injected on the server into html and available for client immediately.

I use this approach to be able to connect many different domains to meteor app and accordingly sent proper data.

Comment: I've done that, using [this](https://meteorhacks.com/fast-render/iron-router-support/) tutorial, but that didn't work. I guess I must have done something wrong then

Comment: I just noticed that FastRender is working. The injected fast-render code is at the bottom of the head of index.html, which means that the routes initialize first, before the collections are initialized. This is exactly what I see in the app when I debug. Is there anything I can do to perform the collection initialization earlier ?

Comment: Check package [Inject-Initial](http://atmospherejs.com/package/inject-initial) which FastRender uses under the hood. Edit html before sending using :`Inject.rawModHtml(id, func)`.

Comment: I checked the documentation, but I don't understand how to use this in combination with fast-renderer. I noticed that I can do `Injected.obj('myData', {...});` on the server and get the data on the client `Injected.obj('myData');` But I'm still very interested in how to use this in combination with collection initialization

Comment: Solved. Updated answer.

Comment: The first works, but the second not, the collections are empty when the routes initialize