# How to route meteor app dynamically on x.myapp.com where x is dynamic?

Tags: meteor, routes, subdomain

I have created two meteor apps. One(www.myapp.com) for displaying list of all authors name and second to show details of author with authors name as subdomain like "authorname.myapp.com".

How it is possible in meteor?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Below approach is used successfully in my apps for more than 1 year.
Please keep in my mind that below code is very simplified and it should be used as inspiration rather than complete solution.

Requires `meteorhacks:fast-render`.

I assume that every `subdomain` has its document in collection `Sites`.

```
subdomain         Sites collection document:
a.example.com     { domain:'a.example.com }
b.example.com     { domain:'b.example.com }
```

The idea is that execution of `Sites.findOne()` on the client will be available in the same time when HTML was received.

### both/collections.js

```
Sites = new Mongo.Collection('sites')
```

### server/routes.js

```
FastRender.onAllRoutes( function ( path ) {
    if ( /(css|js|html|map)/.test( path ) ) {
        return;
    }
    // find subdomain:
    var domain = this.headers.host.split( ":" )[0];

    // subscribe to site publication
    // if domain is in db then send data with HTML file
     this.subscribe('site', domain);
} );


Meteor.publish('site', function(domain){
  return Sites.find( { domain : domain } );
})
```

### client/start.js

```
   if(Meteor.client){
     // if domain was correct then 
     // user should receive document of collection `sites`
     // together with HTML
     var site = Sites.findOne();


     // using site you can display subdomain specific content
   }
```

Should be helpful for you:
[Meteor/Iron-Router: how to define routes using data from settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25422567/meteor-iron-router-how-to-define-routes-using-data-from-settings-json/25423955#25423955)

Comment: where to write this code? in my first app or second app? can you share a sample example if you have?

Comment: My approach is to have **only one app**, where many subdomains point to it. My app is on domain: app.example.com. Then for every new user there is subdomain: X.otherdomain.com. The last thing is to add DNS entry : X.otherdomain.com CNAME app.example.com

Comment: Yes kuba, i want to do this. But my domain name should be fixed like www.example.com and when click on subdomain link it sould be like me.example.com. how can i achieve this ?

Comment: You are doing it in the same way. Simply add DNS entry : **\*.example.com** CNAME **www.example.com**. Subdomain **www.example.com** should point to your server IP ( DNS A entry )